# how to swipe a activity from bottom of screen in android

Tags: android

this is my code,i am using a fragment as a sliding window.but the window is not draggable.

```
            Fragment fg= new addplace();
            FragmentManager f = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = f.beginTransaction().add(R.id.gg,fg);
            trans.commit();

            Interpolator ip = new OvershootInterpolator(5);
            fl.animate().setInterpolator(ip).translationYBy(-200).setDuration(250);

            fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            mlastY=event.getY();
                            return true;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                             double currentY=event.getY();
                             double deltaY=mlastY-currentY;

                            double transY = v.getTranslationY();

                            transY-=deltaY;

                            if(transY<0){
                                transY = 0;
                            }
                            transY=v.getTranslationY();
                    }


                    return false;
                }

            });
            return false;}
    });
}
```

I am not able to drag the screen.If anyone can please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BottomSheet][1].

1. Include `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'` in your dependencies of build.gradle file, in project of Android Studio.
2. Add ViewGroup (LinearLayout,Relativelayout etc.) in your layout file

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="350dp"
   android:clipToPadding="true"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
   app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
   android:fillViewport="true">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@string/ipsum"
       android:padding="16dp"
       android:textSize="16sp"/>
   ```
3. Add code

   ```
   private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
       Button button1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_1 );
       Button button2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_2 );
       Button button3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_3 );

       button1.setOnClickListener(this);
       button2.setOnClickListener(this);
       button3.setOnClickListener(this);

       mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
   }
   ```
4. Show/hide BottomSheet

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch( v.getId() ) {
        case R.id.button_1: {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Full [tutorial][2].


  [1]: https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html
  [2]: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031
```